# Version string portion was too short or too long

Tags: vb.net, version

I'm trying to check the version number of some EXE files I have with VB.Net.

This is the code I found online:

```
Public Class Form1

    '\\ Pulls the file version out of the exe properties
    Private Function GetFileVersionInfo(ByVal filename As String) As Version
        Return Version.Parse(FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filename).ProductVersion)
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Version: " + GetFileVersionInfo("C:\Users\jborg\SkyDrive Pro\Client Software\Malware Tools\HitmanPro.exe").ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The code works perfectly, execept for the EXE listed in the code.

It's giving me the following error:

[image: Error Message]

Here are the file details between a working file, and the not working file:

[image]

Is there something wrong with the EXE as to why I'm getting this error? or is there a better way for me to print the file version number?

Comment: whats the actual string in the bad one?  it looks like it has spaces or something embedded

Comment: The actual string should be the "Product Version" however, if I use the "File Version", which doesn't have spaces, I get the same error.

Comment: So what is the status of this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are in this saga, but if `Parse` is failing on something, you can use `TryParse` to at least avoid the exception:

```
Dim str = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fname).ProductVersion()
If Version.TryParse(str, ver) = False Then
  ...
End If
```

You could also provide your own parser and a default value for any piece which is invalid, missing or otherwise might offend:

```
Dim ver As New Version()
If Version.TryParse(str, ver) = False Then

    Dim parts = str.Split("."c)
    ver = New Version(
        If(parts.Length >= 1, ValueOrDefault(parts(0)), 0),
        If(parts.Length >= 2, ValueOrDefault(parts(1)), 0),
        If(parts.Length >= 3, ValueOrDefault(parts(2)), 0),
        If(parts.Length >= 4, ValueOrDefault(parts(3)), 0)
        )
End If

' a helper function to
' get the int value of a string or 0 if "too long or too short"
Private Function ValueOrDefault(str As String) As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    If Int32.TryParse(str, n) Then
        ' trap for values < 0
        Return If(n < 0, 0, n)
        ' or: Return If(n < 0, 0 - n, n)
    Else
        Return 0
    End If

End Function
```

Given a string with a too large segment: `vstr = "1.435973459374957394.6.7.8"`, the result is `"1.0.6.7"`. The second, oversized value is skipped and a default of 0 is used.

For `"1"` the result is `"1.0.0.0"`, and for "Hello, World!" or any other non numeric or empty string, the result is `0.0.0.0`.